# Cannot deploy to iPad Pro using Visual Studio Tools for Cordova (Update 10)

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, ios-simulator, visual-studio-cordova

I'd like to deploy/debug my Cordova app to the iPad Pro simulator located on my Mac using Visual Studio 2015 (TACO Update 10) but that simulator is not listed in the dropdown in Visual Studio:

[image: List of available devices. iPad Pro is not listed]

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Currently iPad Pro hasn't been targeted in Tools for Apache Cordova.

To workaround this issue, you can :

1. Do the build target any simulator.
2. Copy the platform/iOS folder to your Mac.
3. Open the XCode project in your Mac and target iPad Pro.

For details please refer to [Open a Project within Xcode](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/#open-a-project-within-xcode).

Comment: Our app does not load on any simulator using this technique (blank page after the launch screen -- we can't attach early enough with Safari to know what is the problem). I hope you guys address this issue soon as Apple now requires screenshots for iPad Pro when submitting an App to the store...